# When to implement bluebird library over callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bluebird, endpoint

This is my first time building a full stack react project so any help would be helpful.

Essentially I'm building an endpoint that I would really like to fulfill around 200 request a second. Now looking online that seems like a really reasonable number however since this is my first time doing this I'm not sure if that's true.

Currently using settimeout() I was able to push and resolve 2000ish request or 3000 if you count the preflight request as well in around 3 minutes. This is pretty slow and around 10-20 request per sounds. If I make my request but don't worry resolving the request right away then I can process around 90 request per second. That still isn't what I need in terms of speed and I also would prefer that they are resolved much quicker.

So my current question is would it be better to use the bluebird library because it sounds much faster personally. Also another issue I'm running into when I'm trying to make around 100k+ request is I run out of net resources and I'm not sure how to free up any or how to handle that.

Below is my code

```
const stepData = async() =>{
    try{
        const body = {record,testtime,current_ma,capacity_mah,specap_mah_g,voltage_v}
        assignToBody(body)

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/stepdata',{
                method:"POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })}catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
        setTimeout(delayQue,5000)
        fail = true
        rate = rate + 5
        console.log(rate)
    }
    
}


const delayQue = () =>{

    if(count % 500 == 0 && count > 0 && !fail){
        setTimeout(delayQue,10000)
        assignVals(row)
        row++
        count++
    }
    else if(row < vals.length && !fail){
        setTimeout(delayQue,rate)
        assignVals(row)
        row++
        count++
    }else{
        fail = false
        setTimeout(function(){rate = rate - 5},30000)
    }

}
```

Functions attached to delayQue() that are called through setTimeOut().

```
    const assignVals = (row) =>{

    for(let i = 0; i < possibleCols.length;i++){
        if(cols.includes(possibleCols[i])){
            valsToPass[i] = vals[row][cols.lastIndexOf(possibleCols[i])]
        }else{
            valsToPass[i] = null;
        }
    }
    stepData()
}


const assignToBody = (body) =>{
    for(let i = 0; i < possibleCols.length; i++){
        if(cols.includes(possibleCols[i])){
            body[possibleCols[i]] = valsToPass[cols.lastIndexOf(possibleCols[i])]
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you maging the requests? Perhaps http isnt the best choice for this.

Comment: @TheFool I'm not sure if I understand the question. Essentially I am taking a large file so say 100k lines of text. I am then parsing all the text and storing it into an array of data and sending that data to my server through an endpoint. Did this clarify what you wanted?

Comment: not really, I mean how are you making the requests? Is there a loop somewhere? Do you use await in between requests? Do you use promise.gather? Like how are you making the requests, I cannot tell from your code. Besides of that, I mention that perhaps a different protocol is better for your use case. http requests can be relativly expensive, espeically if its not http2.

Comment: depends probably also on the backend you are hitting with the requests. If it doesn't have much resource or does heavy computation, it will be overwhelmed at some point.

Comment: @TheFool I just updated the code sorry about that. Essentially I'm using a mix of debouncing and throttling to try and optimize the speed. I'm running 500 request at 5 mili sec per request. Then waiting 10 seconds after I've made my 500 request to try and let them resolve before making more. That's the basic breakdown of how all my request are being handled.

In terms of resources I'm not really sure how to handle that issue because with around 100k total request time aside it basically stops processing by 80k request.

Comment: Is this a load test? Or do you genuinely try to transport data by making that many requests?

Comment: you are still not showing how you make the rquest. I dont see a stepData being called.

Comment: @Bergi I'm genuinely trying to make that many request. I hear skepticism or the hint this might be a bad idea. Please let me know why I would love to learn why this isn't the best idea.

Comment: @TheFool I'll add it but essentially my functions are chained together starting with delayQue(). The functions inbetween simply prep the data into an object so I can pass it.

Comment: @boredProjects Yes, that sounds like a bad idea to me. Rather provide an endpoint to which you can pass multiple objects at the same time (e.g. as an array)

Comment: @Bergi I've considered this but should I really store an array in my db?

Comment: @boredProjects No, of course not, you should iterate the array and store each value in a separate database row.

Comment: @Bergi Currently that is what I am doing. I package up the data into an object and the object contains all the values for the corresponding column in that row.